# Macbook airplay to Denon AVR-X4400H — only silence

Tags: macos, audio, airplay

My girlfriend's MacBook connects to my Denon stereo, but no music plays

What we've tried:

- Connect my own MacBook to the Denon. Everything works perfectly.
- Connect her MacBook to the Denon

  - The Demon woke up when she connected
  - When she adjusts the volume slider on the Mac's UI, the volume on the Denon changes accordingly
  - Tried adjusting the volume from the Denon's remote. We can see it change, but still no audio.
  - Hit the mute button on the Denon remote. No joy.

Anything else we could try?

Comment: Have you looked at the System Prefaces/Sound pane to see what's selected?

Comment: I can try this, but I'm pretty sure my Denon was selected, as I can literally see its volume changing as we adjust the volume slider on the Mac.